# tk: make listbox "toggle" or "deselect"

Tags: listbox, tk-toolkit

In tk, the listbox can take a number of different selectModes: single, browse, multiple, and extended. What I want is to be to select only one item at a time (like single or browse) but then deselect the option when the user clicks again - essentially a "single or none" option.

I don't think I can use the ListboxSelect callback because that only is called "when the set of selected item(s) in the listbox is updated" - not when the user clicks a previous selection.

Do I have to resort to a series of checkboxes?

Note: For the listbox, I have exportselection=0 so I don't lose my selection when another widget takes focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to resort to a series of checkboxes, you can simply bind to the buttonpress event, and add a click handler.

Observe, an example:

```
bind $listbox <Button-1> {listbox_selection_toggler %W %x %y}
proc listbox_selection_toggler {W x y} {
    set c [$W cursel]
    set i [$W index @$x,$y]
    lassign [$W bbox $i] x1 y1 x2 y2;
    set x2 [expr {$x1 + $x2}]
    set y2 [expr {$y1 + $y2}]
    if { $y < $y1 || $y > $y2 } {
        puts "(Cur: $c) Clicked on $W at $x,$y, index $i. (NOT IN BBOX)";
    } else {
        puts "(Cur: $c) Clicked on $W at $x,$y, index $i.";
        if { $c != "" && $i == $c } {
            puts "Toggling selection off."
            after 0 [list $W sel clear 0 end]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, obviously there's room for improvement, but this demonstrates the general idea.

Comment: I'll take it your answer is right. I was in Python, and the bindings are definitely the way to go. For user benefit, I actually added an explicit "None Selected" option. Thanks!